# Tablespace details

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am interested in finding certain information about the tablespaces in my database, but I am not quite sure where to begin. I was asked to find the following information:

Summarize in a report, the following:
List all tablespaces including tablespace name, owner, type and total bytes used
By tablespace, list usage statistics,free bytes and fragments

**I was looking around the net and I found this:**

```
select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces
select tablespace_name from user_tablespaces
```

That's about all I have at the moment, but I don't know where to go from there. 
Can someone guide me through what I should to do gather the required information?

Thanks!

Comment: This is better asked on dba

Comment: Why is this tagged both sql-server and Oracle?

Comment: because I am using an oracle db...?

Comment: Tag `Sql-server` is for MS SQL-Server only.

Answer (score 1):

I can help with these...

- Name: dba_tablespaces.Tablespace_Name
- Type (Permanent, Temporary, Undo): dba_tablespaces.Contents
- Size: sum DBA_Data_Files.Bytes for the tablespace
- Free bytes: sum DBA_Free_Space.Bytes for the tablespace
- Total bytes used: Size - Free bytes
- Fragments: Do you mean segments? If so, count DBA_Segments rows for
  the tablespace

... but not the owner; no idea how to find that.

Here's a query to get name, type, size, used, free and segments:

```
WITH
  ts AS (
    SELECT Tablespace_Name, SUM(Bytes/1024) AS TotSize
    FROM DBA_Data_Files
    GROUP BY Tablespace_Name),
  tx AS (SELECT Tablespace_Name, COUNT(*) AS Segments
    FROM DBA_Segments
    GROUP BY Tablespace_Name),
  tf AS (SELECT Tablespace_Name, SUM(Bytes/1024) AS TotFree
    FROM DBA_Free_Space
    GROUP BY Tablespace_Name)
SELECT
  Tablespace_Name,
  DBA_Tablespaces.Contents,
  ts.TotSize,
  ts.TotSize - tf.TotFree AS TotUsed,
  tf.TotFree,
  tx.Segments
FROM DBA_Tablespaces
INNER JOIN ts USING (Tablespace_Name)
INNER JOIN tx USING (Tablespace_Name)
INNER JOIN tf USING (Tablespace_Name)
ORDER BY Tablespace_Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this code. Regarding the types of tablespaces, the only thing I know is that there are temp and regular tablespaces (?) Not 100% sure if temp tablespaces would be considered a different type.

Comment: Here is a list of different types of tablespaces: http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/OTOC520/Default.aspx

Comment: OK, then that's the DBA_Tablespaces.Contents column. According to the Oracle DBA_Tablespaces docs at [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4157.htm) it'll be either PERMANENT, TEMPORARY or UNDO. I'll it to the query above.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :D Btw wouldn't the SYS account be the owner of all tablespaces?

Comment: Btw how do I get usage statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below queries:

Query TS (`TABLESPACE`) information

**`Dba_tablespaces`**

```
SQL>SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,EXTENT_MANAGEMENT,

2         ALLOCATION_TYPE,CONTENTS,

3         SEGMENT_SPACE_MANAGEMENT

4         FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;

TABLESPACE_NAME EXTENT_MAN ALLOCATIO CONTENTS  SEGMEN

————— ———- ——— ——–  ——

SYSTEM      DICTIONARY   USER       PERMANENT MANUAL

UNDOTBS     LOCAL        SYSTEM    UNDO      MANUAL

TEMP        LOCAL        SYSTEM    TEMPORARY MANUAL

TOOL        LOCAL        SYSTEM    PERMANENT MANUAL

USERS       LOCAL        SYSTEM    PERMANENT MANUAL

APP_DATA    DICTIONARY   USER      PERMANENT MANUAL

APP_INDEX   LOCAL        SYSTEM    PERMANENT AUTO
```

**ii. `DBA_FREE_SPACE`**

```
SQL>SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,SUM(BYTES)FREE_SPACE

2 FROM DBA_FREE_SPACE

3 GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME;

TABLESPACE_NAME  FREE_SPACE

————————— ———

APP_DATA                      10481664

APP_INDEX                    10223616

SYSTEM                            88281088

UNDOTBS                         208338944

USERS                                24051712
```

**iii. `DBA_EXTENTS`,`USER_EXTENTS`** – shows information about the extents,extent sizes,associated segment and tablespace.

**`DBA_DATA_FILES`** – shows data files belonging to tablespaces

**`DBA_TEMP_FILES`** – shows temporary files       belonging to locally managed temporary managed tablespaces.

**iv.`DBA_USERS`**

```
SQL>SELECT DEFAULT_TABLESPACE,TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE

2 FROM DBA_USERS

3 WHERE USERNAME = ‘HR’;

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE

——————————- ——————–

EXAMPLE                                TEMP
```

Read all about oracle tablespace and oracle tablspace management here:
http://www.techienawa.com/logical-structure/oracle-tablespace/
http://www.techienawa.com/logical-structure/tablespace-oracle/